# Getting data from API service angular

Tags: angular, rest, http, get, request

I'm learning to create an API with nodejs (express) and angular for the front part.

What should i think and what should i want:
When a user is on www.url.com/**ID** display the data by him **ID**.
But actually i got problem..

Service file gonna get my data.

**ServiceFile.ts**

```
getAllPosts(): Observable<Project[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(this._postsURL)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return <Project[]>response.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
getPost(id: string): Observable<Project> {
        return this.getAllPosts()
            .map(projects => projects.find(project => project._id === id));
    }
```

My component file for get my data throught the ID url example "www.url.com/**ID**" call my service and send to my html file the data

**my component.ts**

```
_postssArray: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            const id = params.get('id');
            this._projectService.getPost(id)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this._postssArray = data;
                        console.log(this._postssArray);
                    }
            );
        });
    }
```

iterate to my data variable send by my component

**View.html file**

```
<div *ngFor="let post of _postssArray">
    <div class="text-cadre">
        <div class="title-cadre">
            <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <p>{{post.text_preview}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**console.log**

Object

> {   _id: "xxxxxxxxxxx",    title: "data",   text_preview: "data data
>   data",   text: "data data" }

Error

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: Your solution lies in the error itself. 
_postssArray is not an array, probably an object. 


ngFor is only iterable on arrays. Please console log the value and check

Comment: I know i'm using an object and this is why it give this error, but i don't find anything for fix it..

Comment: Can you provide the object structure?

Comment: My model file 
export interface Project {
    _id?: string;
    title: string;
    text_preview: string;
    text: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
}

Comment: I mean give me the structure of this._postssArray, not the elements inside it

Comment: i just declare it like this into my component

_postssArray: any;

there is no structure or i don't understand what you said

Comment: You are getting it all wrong, postsArray should be an array of post (in your case where post is an object with the strucuture you provided)
So postsArray = [ { title: 'some', id: '1', ...}, { 'title': 'another', id: '2}]
Angular expects to have postsArray as an array and on iteration it gives you each post

Comment: So my service is wrong ? Should i create an array into my service and push the data and return the array for my component ? 

Or, change postsArray to array ( postsArray = [] ) ? it will return an array right ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your code properly, you probaly don't need to use an ngFor, I have elaborated in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an ngFor here as there is not array. The find function in getPost will always return one post

```
<div class="text-cadre">
        <div class="title-cadre">
            <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <p>{{post.text_preview}}</p>
    </div>

_post: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            const id = params.get('id');
            this._projectService.getPost(id)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this._post = data;
                        console.log(this._post);
                    }
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was a little error from me that's more logic now !